# Probability of 2 complementary angles

Tags: probability, geometry

If $2$ of the given angles, $20º, 70º, 80º, 10º$, are picked at random, what is the probability that they are complementary?

Answer (score 1):

You can pick $2$ angles out of $4$ in $$\dbinom{4}{2}=6$$ possible ways. Now from these ways, the favourable ones are $$(20, 70), (10, 80)$$ and no other. Thus the required probability is equal to $$\frac{\#\{(20,70),(10,80)\}}{\dbinom{4}{2}}=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Pick any angle and there will three angles left. How many of those will be that angle's complement?  Is that the same for all angles?

Answer (score 0):

Successful picks would be (20,70),(70,20),(10,80),(80,10). There are 4 pair 2 possible pairings so that means the answer is $\frac{4}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: No, you have counted the good pairs considering order and all pairs without considering order. This makes you off a factor $2$.

Comment: In your listing of successful picks, ordering matters, so there are $4\times 3$ possible pairings.

Comment: Indeed, I used the choose function when I should have used pair or permutations.